# Login script with denied access to certain page won't work even if SESSION is set

Tags: php, mysql

I've done this login script with protection for certain pages, but even if I type the login correctly it returns me to login page as I didn't have logged in. Already tried to do PHP CODE to show all errors but no errors. Here is the codes:

**LOGIN:**

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");
include("functions.php");




if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['senha']);

$sel_user = "select * from contas where email='$email' AND senha='$pass'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user>0){

$_SESSION['user_email']=$email;

$idUsuario = getIDUsuario($con, $email, $pass);

header('Location: ../paginausuario.php?logado=1&idUsuario=' . $idUsuario);

mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
}

}

?>
```

**PROTECTED PAGE:**

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) {
header('Location: lib/logout.php');
} else { ?>
```

**LOGIN FORM:**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) { ?>

<form id="signin" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="lib/logout.php">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sair</button>
</form>

<?php } else { ?> 

<form id="signin" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="lib/login.php" method="POST">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="Seu e-mail">                                        
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" value="" placeholder="Sua senha">                                        
</div>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't see `session_start()` anywhere

Comment: @Machavity True, but as "my" experiences on Stack and for many before, 99% of the time they turn around and say *"the session is started"* but fail to mention that.

Comment: *"Already tried to do PHP CODE to show all errors but no errors."* - Oh, where and how? If done properly and the session hasn't been started, you should have been thrown a whole slew of notices. We also don't know what `getIDUsuario()` does.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hence why I didn't post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @Machavity I don't blame you. Personally, I don't post answers for sessions-related questions anymore and I've made that decision a long time ago. There are far too many things that *always* go wrong and of course, this is based on my own personal experience with questions like these; hence my "comments" when dealing with sessions-related questions ;-)

Comment: *"but even if I type the login correctly it returns me to login page* - Your query failed and you need to find out why that is. Too many things can be at play here; if the data is correct and complete; if the columns are of the right type and lenght, etc. etc. etc. the list goes on. Check for errors which you are not doing. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the session start call anywhere:

```
session_start();
```

Remember to start sessions at the very beginning of each of your scripts.

Comment: about 2 mins to go to *possibly* see a green tick ;-) if we don't see one, then something else is causing their code to fail. But... let's not leave that out of the equation.

Comment: haha SO should have a countdown functionallity with a bet system, where users can bet using reputation as currency...

Comment: Ouuhhh, I like that idea!

Comment: seems like the question's gone stale, or gone South, or gone somewhere that the OP didn't invite any of us to go to; *hmph!*

Comment: Hahahah you are all funny, guys! I thought about it, but in my login.php I thought that $_SESSION['user_email']=$email; worked as a session_start! I put it there and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Fred-ii- took longer than 2 mins... should have placed my bet :p

Comment: welll well, will you lookah dat. A green tick! *finally*

Comment: @taxicala I should've taken that bet also. Had the odds been 50 to 1, it'd of been a pretty big payoff ;-)

Comment: we should fund SO Bets.

Comment: ...it has potential for sure. I like the idea hehe